# JQuery/Javascript - Need RegEx to match the multilingual text

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am using the below jQuery code to search the text on the page, but this does not search the French or other language text on the web page. The jQuery code used is as below -

```
phrase = ["\\b(", phrase, ")"].join("");

//search for any matches
var count = 0;
$("#faq-container p").each(
    function (i, v) {
        //replace any matches
        var block = $(v);
        block.html(
            block.text().replace(
                //new RegExp(phrase, "gi"), function (match) { // properties used g , i => g -> global : Whether to test the regular expression against all possible matches in a string, or only against the first.
                // i -> ignoreCase : Whether to ignore case while attempting a match in a string.
                phrase, function (match) {
                    count++;
                    return ["<span class='highlight'>", match, "</span>"].join("");
                }
            )
        );
    }
);
```

Comment: That's an unusual coding style for JavaScript!

Comment: why do you think this is unusual coding style for Javascript? I needed this code to search the text on the web page and highlight the matching text.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style -- But I see it was edited.

Comment: The code looks well indented for me...

Comment: It is now, at the time of posting it looked like https://gist.github.com/7b44be227ff48123887b

Comment: Ok.. thanks for your time.. Any idea how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved by just removing the line below line -

phrase = ["\b(", phrase, ")"].join("");

I dont know somehow with this line it does not match the other language text(other than English)....